# Tips for optimization (THEOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jailbreak, theos

i am writing my first tweak for iOS using theos and I am stuck at optimization.As i can see,dylib will check every time(every second?) "([[settings objectForKey:@"something"] boolValue])" and "[[settings objectForKey:@"SomethingHere"] boolValue]" in plist file.

Is it OK?
Any suggestion for optimization?
Here is my tweak :

```
%hook Something
- (void)somethingheree:(_Bool)arg1 withNumberOfDevices:(int)arg2
{
    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Preferences/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), @"com.yourcompany.mytweak.plist"]];

       if([[settings objectForKey:@"something"] boolValue]) {
        %orig(YES,100);
    }
    else %orig;

}
%end

%hook somethinganother
- (void)somethinghere:(_Bool)arg1
{
    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Preferences/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), @"com.yourcompany.mytweak.plist"]];
       if([[settings objectForKey:@"SomethingHere"] boolValue]) {
        %orig(NO);
    } else %orig;
}
%end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PreferenceLoader for your preferences panel, you can save the value in a global variable and use darwin notifications to monitor the changes of preferences. You can find a lot examples in open source tweaks, such as one of mine:

https://github.com/Qusic/MailtoOpener/blob/master/Tweak.mm#L192